# Ionic 2 half height modal

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

So in the docs it says that we can pass in CSS classes:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/#create

```
  presentProfileModal() {
    const modalOpt: ModalOptions = {
      cssClass: "my-modal"
    }
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SampleModalPage, {}, modalOpt);
    profileModal.present();
  }
```

Where do I define that "my-modal"? Does it go in the app.scss? Or the current page's scss which has the above function? I'm not sure where to place that class. My follow up question is how to pull up the modal only until half of the screen instead of the full screen. `max-height: 50%`?

Comment: I have tried .my-modal {mex-height: 50%;} in the current page's .scss file and also in SampleModalPage's .scss file but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Add your css in app.scss

Comment: That's not working.